# Android - Get user games data (games played, achievements unlocked...)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Basically, what I am trying to do is to get the user's data from all the games that he played, as 'Play Games' app do. I want to know the user's games played, achievements and so on.

I have tried the Google Sing in but it requires a game from my Google Developer Console to get data from.

All the information I found around the internet are for your own game, at this point I am wondering if it is even possible to achieve what I am trying to do.

After hours searching, I decide to ask for help here.

Thank you in advance for all.